# replace all selected json objects with a different object

Tags: json, visual-studio-code

I am using visual studio code Version 1.19.3, and I have 174 occurrences of a specific json object which I would like to replace with a different object. Is there an easy way to do this in visual studio code? find and replace doesn't work because of the tabs.

Answer (score 0):

You can search and replace tabs in vscode but perhaps you have your tabs converted to spaces as your default indentation.  If you try <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>P</kbd> and "`Convert Indentation to Tabs`" then search and replace for \t will work as you expect (with the Use Regular Expression button clicked).

Then you could back to indentation with spaces by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>P</kbd> and "`Convert Indentation to Spaces`" if you wish when you are done.